# Username has left the chat message when his session ends?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Basically I have a chat, using AJAX, PHP.

I let guests login by filling their name and clicking login.
It fills the session `$_SESSION['guest']`.

Now, when they close their browsers, or something, once the session ends, I want it to say in the chat

"The username has left the chat".

But I am not sure on how would I do this.
Any ways to do it? Maybe I could fill an array of users that were active in the past 5 minutes, if not, remove from the array and it will kick them off the chat.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible in PHP, but can you listen for a socket close?

Comment: your last thought on how to do it would work, another way would be to loop over all active sessions and compare that to an array of active users, and if the user's session is no longer active, show them leaving.

Comment: Use a comet or a long-poll... that is what you are wanting

Comment: Why not just `echo` the message right after where you have the ended session directive, and use CSS it?

Comment: Maybe something like this: `if(isset($_SESSION['guest'])) { echo '<div class="logged_out">The $username has left the chat</div>'; unset($_SESSION['guest']); }`

Answer (score 1):

You could have an array of users in the backend with the timestamp of the last ping.

Then, the clients end can update the backend using ajax by sending a new timestamp every so many seconds.

Whilst your backend is being updated by one of the users, your backend can do a check on all users checking the last timestamp sent to the current time, if its over 2 minutes or something you can tell they have left the chat and output the message.

Comment: With this method, you could also keep the timestamp in a database and save it as a 'Last online date'

Answer (score 0):

Without a direct connection to the browser, you won't be able to actively tell if they're connected. I'd suggest a ping-like solution, requiring the browser to ping the server every `n` seconds to keep the chat "alive".

If the browser doesn't "check in" with the server, the server assumes they've disconnected and reports back to the other participant.

That said, if you're able to dive a little deeper, Google "javascript real-time chat" and you'll have [several paths to success](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socket-io-and-expressjs/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a jQuery .unload() event to your chat client. When they navigate away from the chat it will be fired and you can use it to send the last bit of data to display that message.

Here is the documentation: [Link](http://api.jquery.com/unload/).

Example:

```
    $(window).unload(function() {
      //send message to server informing it of client leaving
    });
```